# How can I execute a single SQL query with multiple semicolon from Spring JDBC to PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, procedure, spring-jdbc

I´m trying execute:

```
String query = "begin package.function(1); end; ";      

this.getJdbcTemplate().execute(query);
```

But when it runs, throw this exception:

> nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: missing
>   ";" at end of SQL statement
>
> Where: statement: "begin
>   olab_proc_recalculo_ord_fac.proc_recalcula_orden (0)" anonymous SPL
>   block at line 1] with root cause org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
>   ERROR: missing ";" at end of SQL statement   Where: statement: "begin
>   olab_proc_recalculo_ord_fac.proc_recalcula_orden (0)" anonymous SPL
>   block at line 1

Ok, I understand that my query is ending at `(1);` but wihtout that semicolon, query not run in pgAdmin.

How can I run this query?

Answer (score 0):

The missing semicolon is after [`begin`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-begin.html):

```java
String query = "begin; package.function(1); end; ";
```